# MVC form data cant bind to the model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a MVC form where I am posting this data from JS over to this controller. I cant get this data to bind to the model. The current model is looking for the hidden field to be QuestionType[int] but I am not sure how to do that ant help would be great

html

```
<input data-val="true" data-val-required="The Char field is required." id="item_QuestionType_0_" name="item.QuestionType[0]" type="hidden" value="L">
```

view

```
@model List<MeetingPolling>
     int idx = 0;
     foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        @Html.HiddenFor(m => Model[idx].QuestionType)
                        @Html.HiddenFor(x => item.QuestionType, new { @id = string.Format("hfQuestionType{0}", item.labelControl), @name = string.Format("hfQuestionType{0}", item.labelControl), Value = item.QuestionType })
                     </div>
                </div>
                idx++;
             }
```

current serialize data

```
item.QuestionType=LongAnswerText&1=sssssssssssssssssssssss&item.QuestionType=MultipleChoice&16=75
```

what model is looking for to be able to bind

```
QuestionType%5B0%5D=LongAnswerText&textboxfor_1=456456456456456456&QuestionType%5B1%5D=MultipleChoice&radioList_16=75
```

Model

```
public class PollingResponseFormViewModel
{
    public List<string> QuestionType { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: `@name = "hfQuestionType"` <-- This is why. ASP.NET **needs** to use its own generated `name=""` attributes to bind POSTed data to view-model properties. If you force-override your own `name=""` attribute then ASP.NET can't bind it.

Comment: The `HiddenFor()` extension-method will render automatically-generated (and unique) `id=""` and `name=""` attributes for you already, why are you doing it yourself?

Comment: ...another issue is that ASP.NET cannot bind a single posted field to a `List<String>` property - you need a loop to render each entry. ASP.NET requires its own custom list binding syntax: it doesn't support binding a `List<String>` to repeated identical form field names.

Comment: **Also**: `@Html.HiddenFor(x => item.QuestionType` <-- This is completely wrong: you need to use the `x` parameter, not whatever `item` is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use a single `Html.HiddenFor()` field for a `List<String>` - you need to render those hidden inputs this way:

```
@for( Int32 i = 0; i < this.Model.QuestionType.Count; i++ ) {
    @Html.HiddenFor( m => m.QuestionType[i] )
}
```

You must use `for`, not `foreach( var foo in this.Model.QuestionType )` because the `Expression<>` passed into `HiddenFor` needs the `int` indexer for the `List<T>` property.

---

Also, change your view-model so `QuestionType` is a pre-initialized, `get`-only property, as otherwise it will be `null` by default and mess with everything:

```
public class PollingResponseFormViewModel
{
    public List<string> QuestionType { get; } = new List<String>();
}
```

Comment: Sorry the model for the view is a list @model List<MeetingPolling> and I am looping that list which is that `item.QuestionType` I am doing `foreach (var item in Model)`

Comment: ...why did you waste my time with a question that doesn't match your actual code at all then? Please edit your post to show you **actual** code.

Comment: Sorry I didnt think that was the problem I updated the question

Comment: can I access it using the model something like this  @Html.HiddenFor(m => Model[idx].QuestionType)

Comment: No, because you aren’t using the `m` parameter. You can’t use the `Model` property directly inside IHtmlHelper Expressions.

Comment: so is there any other way to do this?

Comment: Why can’t you use `PollingResponseFormViewModel` as-is from your original post?

Comment: I was thinking it was because of the format `item.QuestionType`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249254/discussion-between-jefferson-and-dai).